# Zend framework retrieving email

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

When trying to implement this framework I ran into a issue with the directory. When I attemt to use this Zend i end up with

```
 Interface 'Zend\Mail\Storage\Folder\FolderInterface' not found in /home/content/54/9595754/html/zend/library/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php
```

In the index.php file where I try to display the emails. I use an:

```
 set_include_path     
 include require_once('Imap.php');
```

The contents of Imap.php looks like:

```
 namespace Zend\Mail\Storage;

 use Zend\Mail;
 use Zend\Mail\Protocol;

 class Imap extends AbstractStorage implements Folder\FolderInterface,     Writable\WritableInterface
```

So what would i need to add to the Imap.php so that it dosent look inside this directory for the file.

I know understand that I need to try to implement a file in order for the framework to understand the directory they are in however when i try to implement an autoloader  I get an error see example below.

```
require_once '../../../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

Yields

```
require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in /home/content/54/9595754/html/zend/library/Zend/
Loader/Autoloader.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend framework 2 and most other modern frameworks rely on [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for class loading.
You have only required the Imap class but not the dependent interfaces. That's why you get this fatal error.
I'd suggest you setup autoloading in your application. For an example how to set this up you can have a look into [init_autoloader.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php) from the ZendSkeletonApplication.

Comment: Yes this is without a doubt my first attempt at using a framework! so I include-once the init_autoloader.php within my index.php? I dont need to actually call the imap.php correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be sufficient. All ZF2 classes are named following [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) rules. The FQCN (class name including namespaces) reflects the folder structure, so the classloader nows where to find the files. It is recommended to active classmap autoloader in production because it has better performance, you should read up about that.

Comment: 1st I used the require_once and pointed to the Autoloader.php file and when i do this I get an error due to one of the first line within the Autoloader file is require_once(Zend/Loader.php) The error i get is ,`Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/54/9595754/html/zend/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php`  I also tried including the AutoloaderFactory.php This time yeilding an error that `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader' not found in /home/content/54/9595754/html/zend/demos/Zend/Mail/SimpleMailer.php`

Comment: Do you know about [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)? This will make it easy to install and update your project dependencies. You can also install complete ZF2 library or seperate ZF2 components and it will take care of all autoloading setup. Your issues with trying to get it running manually are because of your ZF2 library path not been found (you can try defining that in your include_path). Also it's strange `Zend_Loader` is instanciated, because this seems like a ZF1 class.

Comment: It's difficult to help you with this kind of problems remote. You should try to debug what is happening yourself. At least you could give composer a try. I'm using it for all my projects and love it!

Comment: I am currently using ZF1 and hosting through Godaddy to install i simply downloaded the zip file and uploaded the folder structure to my the root of my shared hosting linux server

Comment: You've tagged your question with ZF2.. Most of my suggestions are specificaly targetted on ZF2. Is there a reason if you are starting out with a framework to use ZF1? If you are starting a new project I highly suggest to use a newer framework (i.e. ZF2 or Symfony2).

Comment: I have been trying both...I did however attempt the solution u posed in ZF1 and not ZF2 ill try it now and post my findings. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: With ZF2 I can use the `require_once 'zend2/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';` successfully note that autoloader.php doesn't exists only the factory one in the zip file I got. When running code that looks like `require_once 'zend2/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
use Zend\Mail\Message;` I get an error stating `Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mail\Message' not found in /home/content/54/9595754/html/text.php on line 7`

Comment: I have notice a few people code including the folowing statement `function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}` could this be my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have to go now and I'm not online in the next 24 hours. Try installing the complete [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) or use the init_autoloader.php file from that project. The skeleton is a great start to get a ZF2 app up and running.

Comment: unfortunately the skeleton doesnt include the only functionality im looking for MAIL